# SQL partition by on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume this is my table:

```
ID  NUMBER  DATE
------------------------
1   45      2018-01-01
2   45      2018-01-02
2   45      2018-01-27
```

I need to separate using partition by and row_number where the difference between one date and another is greater than 5 days. Something like this would be the result of the above example:

```
ROWNUMBER   ID  NUMBER  DATE
-----------------------------
1           1   45      2018-01-01
2           2   45      2018-01-02
1           3   45      2018-01-27
```

My actual query is something like this:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NUMBER ODER BY ID DESC) AS ROWNUMBER, ...`

But as you can notice, it doesn't work for the dates. How can I achieve that?

Comment: make a date table with start date range and end date range, then give each range an id.  Join to the date table by date, and partition by the id of the date range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lag` function :

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by number, grp order by id) as [ROWNUMBER]
from (select *, (case when datediff(day, lag(date,1,date) over (partition by number order by id), date) <= 1 
                      then 1 else 2 
                 end) as grp
      from table
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

by using `lag` and `datediff` funtion

```
select * from
    (
    select t.*,
           datediff(day,
                    lag(DATE) over (partition by NUMBER order by id),
                    DATE
                   ) as diff
    from  t 
      ) as TT where  diff>5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/130ae/11

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to identify the *groups*, using `lag()` and `datediff()` and a cumulative sum.  *Then* use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by number, grp order by date) as rownumber
from (select t.*,
             sum(grp_start) over (partition by number order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(date) over (partition by number order by date) < dateadd(day, 5, date)
                            then 1 else 0
                    end) as grp_start
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```